# Regex fixed number of characters but any quantity of spaces

Tags: regex

I'm validating some input fields. Here's the regex for a simple example:

```
^\[0-9]\{6,6}\$
```

In the example, it requires 6 numbers to be input. However, I want to relax the validation a little and allow spaces where necessary, and remove them later - an example might be a bank sort code.

In the UK, a sort code could be written as 123456, or perhaps 12 34 56.

I know I can amend the expression to include a space within the brackets and relax the numbers in the curly brackets, but what I'd like to do is continue to limit the digits so that 6 must always be input, and allow none or more spaces - of course the spaces could be anywhere.

I'm not sure how to approach this - any ideas, help appreciated.

Comment: What is the language/tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\d\s*){6}$
```

It allows 0 or more whitespace characters after every digit.

If you want to limit whitespace to be inside the digits (without leading or trailing spaces):

```
^(\d\s*){5}\d$
```

Comment: FYI this regex does not match the valid number ` 123456`

Comment: @MaxZoom OP didn't state exactly where spaces are allowed (before, after, inside...). I explained what each of the 2 versions do, and if it is required to support leading spaces as well, it's simple to adopt.

Comment: it seems that 6 digits with any space location should be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

If you allow spaces at *any* position alongside 6 digits, then you need

```
^(\s*[0-9]){6}\s*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%5cs*%5b0-9%5d)%7b6%7d%5cs*%24&i=12+34+56+)

The `\s*`  matches any whitespace, 0 or more repetitions.

Note that a limiting quantifier `{6,6}` (minimum 6 and maximum 6 repetitions) is equal to `{6}`.

Also, note that you need to double escape the `\s` as `\\s` if you pass the  regex pattern as a regular string literal.

And if you plan to only allow regular spaces, not all whitespace, just use

```
^([ ]*[0-9]){6}[ ]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at a lookahead expression

[This site](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) explains them in more detail

For your example, `^(?=(\s*[0-9]\s*){6})(\d*\s*)$`

This looks for any amount of space, followed by a digit followed by any amount of space 6 times.

Other answers I've seen so far only allow a total of 6 characters, this expression will allow any number of spaces but only 6 digits, no more, no less.

Note: `^(\s*[0-9]\s*){6}$` this will also work, without the lookahead expression

[JavaScript Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d81aqvbz/)